# Popover controller not dismiss when click on other bar button but dismiss when click other button(or outside popover)

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, dismiss, uipopover

I show a popover using - "presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem" - after that the popover will not dismiss when I click on the other bar button item in right navigation bar buttons.

But dismiss the popover when I click elsewhere.
Also the issue is not there when we show popover using - " presentPopoverFromRect: inView: " - strange?.

Since we don't get the frame from UIBarButtonItem How can I show a popover correctly from barbutton.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question to help some one,

```
// Presenting from BarButton will not dismiss popover when we click on other bar button.
// [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.barButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (UIView *subview in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]])   {
        [buttons addObject:subview];
    }
}

UIView *view = [buttons objectAtIndex:1]; // The '1' is the index to your bar item in the array of .items

CGRect barButtonFrame = [self.navigationController.navigationBar convertRect:view.frame toView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:barButtonFrame inView:self.navigationController.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

What I did above is find the frame of bar button and show popover "presentPopoverFromRect".

Answer (score 0):

I do no,whether you used nib or xib in popover controller or not,but let try below code

```
 if (_Popover != nil) {
        [_Popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [_Popover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    }
```

Comment: But i my case there is 5 barbutton each using different popover instance. Now I fixed with this solution. But why this two presentation method behave differently.